# Who was the dead Voyager crew member discovered by the two Voth archaeologists?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In the first act of *Voyager* episode ["Distant Origin"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Distant_Origin_(episode)), we see two Voth archaeologists recover the human skeletal remains of a Voyager crew member in a cave on an M-class planet.

Strangely, the remains were never identified in the episode. Are they any clues in prior episodes how a Voyager crew member died on this planet? And why his corpse was not retrieved?

Comment: This website shows a picture of what the crew member looked like before becoming a skeleton. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Distant_Origin_Theory Perhaps somebody can identify this character.

Comment: Looks a lot like the dude from Allen Nation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Although the character isn't named in the episode, The [**Star Trek Voyager Companion**](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Voyager_Companion) (billed as the *"official companion to Star Trek: Voyager"*) identifies the remains as belonging to **[Ensign Hogan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hogan)**, the maquis crewman who was killed in a cave in [VOY: Basics](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Basics,_Part_II_(episode))

[image]

You can see the similarity in the caves in the shots below.

[image]

Comment: I think the votes and the check were quite properly given. Even added one. However, I wouldn't necessarily consider reuse of the same outdoors set by the production company as incontrovertible proof that they are supposed to be representing the same place in the universe. Their budgets, while probably better than TOS, weren't unlimited.

Comment: [This script for *Distant Origins*](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/318.htm) explicitly mentions Hogan in the notes, though I don't know whether that script is canon.  I marathoned Voyager a couple years ago, and I distinctly remember making the connection between the episodes even if it wasn't explicit.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede - That isn't a script, it's a fan-written transcript

Comment: @T.E.D. I can understand the same location being used in two different episodes (eg, Vasquez Rocks), but also reproducing the exact camera angle, too?

Comment: @RobertF - I'm with you, except.... what if that's the only angle that presents properly?

Answer (score 20):

The remains were those of Maquis crewman [Hogan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hogan), a recurring character in the second and third seasons, who died in the third season premier (["Basics, Part 2"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Basics,_Part_II_(episode))).  The Kazon had stranded Voyager's crew on a primitive planet, and Hogan fell prey to a large animal while investigating a cave.  Due to the danger posed by the animal, Hogan's crewmates were unable to retrieve his remains.

[image: Crewman Hogan]

Source: [Hogan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hogan) (actor [Simon Billig](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Simon_Billig)) | Memory Alpha

Comment: Not to seem overly harsh, but memory alpha is a fan-written wiki. Do they offer any specific *evidence* that this is Hogan?

Comment: @Valorum - I understand; the Memory Alpha links are bonus content.  I think that the settings of the primary sources (episodes Basics, Part II and Distant Origin) make it clear that this is the same person.

Comment: "Hogan fell prey to a large animal" I'd more accurately characterise it as "Hogan fell prey to Neelix's incompetence" ;)

Comment: @Muzer Neelix is a *relatively* large animal.

Answer (score 3):

That unfortunate crewman was killed by an critter while exploring the surroundings, when the Kazon left the crew of the Voyager on a deserted planet to die.

It happened in the first episode of season three.

Comment: On what are you basing this?

Comment: I'd Need to watch that episodes/scenes again, but i think it was quite obvious that it was the same cave. i think i should make some screengrabs

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the remains were supposed to be Hogan, but the only issue I see is that Hogan's uniform was retrieved in Basics part 2 and used by Chakotay to make a water filtration system, including his rank insignia.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on earlier answers rather than a new answer to the question.

Comment: @Blackwood Users can't post comments until they have 50+ reputation. They are expected to respect this by only posting real answers until they have earned the required reputation.

Answer (score 1):

In basics part 2 an unnamed character in a blue uniform was pulled off a rock and part eaten by the same creature, before they blocked the cave up so the creature would slowly starve to death.. perhaps it could have been his remains?

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but see my answer above. The official word is that it was Hogan